# dat.gui not rendering properly in WebGL window

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, dat.gui

When i try to render my dat.gui with a button and a textbox on top of my WebGL window i get this:

[image: The button and the textbox is not showing]

The "Close Controls" part of the dat.gui is showing, but for some reason my button and textbox is not. I use three.js to create the WebGL window.

```js
function ini()
{
    this.button1 = function () { alert("HEJ"); };
    this.text1 = "Hallo World";
}

var gui = new dat.GUI({ autoPlace: false });
var div = document.getElementById('datGui');
div.appendChild(gui.domElement);
var i = new ini();
gui.add(i, "button1");
gui.add(i, "text1");
```

```html
<div id="datGui">
 <canvas id="canvas" style="position: absolute; background-color: black; width: auto; "></canvas> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are trying to restrict dat.GUI and it does not like it. Try removing these two lines: `var div = document.getElementById('datGui');
div.appendChild(gui.domElement);`

Comment: removing those lines does make the dat.gui render correctly. However, dat.gui is no longer rendered inside the WebGL window. Instead it is rendered in the top-right corner of the website.
The reason i wrote the two lines of code was to have dat.gui rendered inside of my WebGL window.

Comment: could it be that the z-index of the two elements are fighting?

Comment: No, but that was also my first guess

Comment: you could try looking into this page http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshLambertMaterial that does render the dat.gui in the webgl window.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's a bug in dat.gui. Solution: Don't use dat.gui, it is very buggy in general

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this code pen demonstrates the zIndex effect on the document and dat gui rendering : https://codepen.io/ubermario/pen/PBpMNN/

...

```
document.getElementById("canvas").style.zIndex = "-1";
```

...